# gnugk, openmcu and tandberg VC Unit

Tags: voip

im testing gnugk, openmcu along with a few tandberg vc units for a video conference call.
my config is....
gnugk + openmcu => 10.21.34.2
tandberg vc =>10.21.34.151..

When i invite VC for conference for the fist time from openmcu web interface, it connect for a while and it shows connecting but soon the call terminates itself.

A few log messages from gnugk are (at the time of conecting and disconnecting)...

```
011/06/27 17:59:57.968  3   ProxyChannel.cxx(965)   Q931d   Received: Alerting CRV=24075 from 10.21.34.151:1720
2011/06/27 18:00:01.978 3   ProxyChannel.cxx(965)   Q931d   Received: Connect CRV=24075 from 10.21.34.151:1720
2011/06/27 18:00:01.978 2         gkacct.cxx(1043)  GKACCT  Successfully logged event 32 for call no. 18
2011/06/27 18:00:01.978 3   ProxyChannel.cxx(4400)  H245    Set h245Address to 10.21.34.2:53057
2011/06/27 18:00:01.981 3   ProxyChannel.cxx(4319)  H245    Connected from 10.21.34.2:46867 on 10.21.34.2:53057
2011/06/27 18:00:01.982 3   ProxyChannel.cxx(4351)  H245    Connect to 10.21.34.151:11011 from 10.21.34.2:0 successful
2011/06/27 18:00:02.080 3   ProxyChannel.cxx(1163)  H245    ERROR DECODING H.245 from 10.21.34.2:43717
2011/06/27 18:00:11.993 3   ProxyChannel.cxx(965)   Q931s   Received: ReleaseComplete CRV=24075 from 10.21.34.2:43717
2011/06/27 18:00:11.993 1         RasTbl.cxx(3534)  CDR|18|06 78 94 d6 26 9f e0 11 90 3b 00 0c 29 21 33 74|10|Mon, 27 Jun 2011 18:00:01 +0530|Mon, 27 Jun 2011 18:00:11 +0530|10.21.34.2:43717|4125_endp|10.21.34.151:1720|4121_endp|10.21.34.151:1720|OpenH323 MCU v2.2.1:h323_ID|GnuGk;
```

Any help can enlighten me...

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your GnuGk can't decode one of the H.245 messages. Are you using the latest version (2.3.4) ?

This might be something to ask on the GnuGk mailinglist (subscribe through [www.gnugk.org](http://www.gnugk.org/)).

Comment: im using 2.3.0. well pretty recent. That's what is available as precompiled binaries on ubuntu...